# Nella condizione in cui, utilizzo

Tags: phrase-choice, sentences, subjunctive-mood

Quando è possibile utilizzare "nella condizione in cui" con il congiuntivo?

Il dubbio nasce dal fatto che si potrebbe utilizzare "a condizione che" perché "nella condizione in cui" sembra indicare una situazione già prestabilita, che per qualche motivo potrebbe non aver bisogno del congiuntivo.

Per esempio "riesco a misurare questa quantità nella condizione in cui siano aperti i generatori di corrente del circuito"

Oppure "riesco a misurare questa quantità nella condizione in cui sono aperti i generatori di corrente del circuito"

Il problema nasce dal fatto che in realtà, perché sia possibile fare la misura, i generatori devono necessariamente essere aperti.

Potete indicarmi la frase più corretta tra le due e la frase più corretta in assoluto?

Grazie

Comment: "A condizione che" indica un prerequisito necessario affinché si possa verificare qualcosa.
"Nella condizione in cui" mi pare solo descrittivo ma non ha lo stesso significato di requisito. "Per poter misurare questa quantità dobbiamo metterci nella condizione in cui i generatori sono aperti". È il contesto che fornisce il significato di requisito (dobbiamo metterci).

Comment: *Riesco a misurare questa quantità purché siano aperti…* dice che puoi farlo solo quando i generatori di corrente sono aperti. Invece di *purché* si potrebbe adoperare *a condizione che*, ma è meglio preferire una parola a tre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negli esempi che riporti, le parole "nella condizione in cui" rappresentano un tipico esempio di locuzione inutile, infatti lo stesso significato si può ottenere con "se", o "solo se", e in questo caso è evidente che va usato l'indicativo.

"Riesco a misurare questa quantità (solo) se sono aperti i generatori di corrente del circuito."

La ragione per cui si può usare una locuzione come quella sopra è il desiderio di rendere la frase contorta e difficile da capire, il che a volte è un effetto richiesto; allora l'uso del congiuntivo può certamente aiutare a complicare ulteriormente il tutto, al di là della correttezza grammaticale.

In ogni caso non si capisce se la condizione dei generatori di corrente aperti sia solo necessaria o anche sufficiente. Generatori di corrente aperti? Tensione infinita!

Comment: Da quando l uso del congiuntivo complica le cose? Un ottima e valida alternativa può essere anche "qualora" e qui il più delle volte il congiuntivo fa da compagno fisso!

Comment: Il congiuntivo non complica le cose per sua natura, volevo solo dire che, in questa particolare circostanza, se si usa il congiuntivo il senso della frase diventa meno chiaro, per cui che legge non potrà capire se la condizione dei generatori aperti sia necessaria per la misura oppure semplicemente non la ostacoli.